# Programmatically adding constraints to a UITableView header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a header on my tableview, which has an image and a label. I want to center the UIImage and have the label pinned underneath it. This is my code currently:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerLabel = UILabel()
    let logoView = UIImageView()

    headerLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 21)
    headerLabel.text = self.navigationItem.title
    headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

    logoView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: 90)
    let logo: UIImage = UIImage(named: self.navigationItem.title!)!
    logoView.image = logo
    logoView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    view.addSubview(headerLabel)
    view.addSubview(logoView)

    return topView
}
```

This puts the label centered on the top of the header, and the logo in the top left corner. How can I add constraints (programmatically, no storyboard) to center the image and pink the label below it? I've been using programmatic constraints quite a bit (i.e. `something.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo....`) but I'm not sure how to apply it in this situation as it's my first use of a header.

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom view class for your header and adding all the frames/constraints there? Then load that view in this same viewForHeaderInSection method?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. When you say `view.addSubview`, what is `view`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to center the UIImage and have the label pinned underneath it.

This can be achieved by making the framing logic of each subview dependent of the neighbouring views. Whilst doing this programmatically, one has to be extra careful about the geometric calculations involved.

This snippet should do it:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let logoView = UIImageView()

    logoView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.center.x - 90/2, y: 0, width: 90, height: 90)
    let logo: UIImage = UIImage(named: self.navigationItem.title!)!
    logoView.image = logo
    logoView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    view.addSubview(logoView)

    let headerLabel = UILabel()
    headerLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: logoView.frame.size.height, width: view.frame.width, height: 21)
    headerLabel.text = self.navigationItem.title
    headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

    view.addSubview(headerLabel)

    return topView
}
```

Comment: Very close! Using your code, the logo is in the middle but still stuck right at the top of the header, I'd like it more in the center of the header. And a bit of padding between the top of the label and the bottom of the logo. I'll probably just have to adjust the y values?

Comment: Ok, I just added 20 to both y values. Thanks a lot!

Comment: glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

You can use that code to set default paddings.

`if #available(iOS 15.0, *) { tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0 }`